# WPF VisualStateManager Changing Child Properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a *ScrollViewer* with some nested child elements like this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MainScrollViewer"...>
    <Grid ...>
        <TextBlock ... FontSize="20" ...>
        <StackPanel ...>
            <TextBlock ... FontSize="15" ...>
            ...
            <TextBlock ... FontSize="15" ...>
        </StackPanel ...>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Most of the *TextBlock*s have a *FontSize* set explicitly in the control.

I'm writing a Windows Universal app and so I am using the Visual State Manager to take care of different window sizes.  I need to change the font size of all child elements within *MainScrollViewer* for one of the visual states.

I tried setting the *FontSize* using one of the setters for a particular visual state as such:

```
<Setter Target="MainScrollViewer.FontSize" Value="10">
```

This seems to have no effect, as it is not overriding the values.  **How can I override all font sizes of child elements using a VSM Setter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no better solution comes up you could take one `TextBlock` as the font size master and all other TextBlocks bind to that master. Doing so you only need to set the font size of the master in the VSM.

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="FonSizeMaster" FontSize="20" ... />
    <TextBlock FontSize="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=FonSizeMaster}" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a good example for VSM

Manages states and the logic for transitioning between states for controls.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since FontSize is an attached property the following should also work (not tested):

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MainScrollViewer" TextElement.FontSize="20" ...>
    <Grid ...>
    <TextBlock ... >
    <StackPanel ...>
        <TextBlock ... >
        ...
        <TextBlock ... >
    </StackPanel ...>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

VSM:

```
<Setter TargetName="MainScrollViewer" Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="10">
```